# How to use 'this' in strict mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular service, let's call it ActionService, which uses 
'use strict'. So because of that, whenever I use **this** to call a method of its own, it is undefinded. Is there way to bypass the strict use?

```
if (angular.isFunction(this[action.name])) {
   this[action.name](parameters);
} else {
   doSpecialAction(action, parameters);
}
```

Comment: can you use `var self = this;` and then call `self[...]`?

Comment: `it is undefinded`  for a good reason, without `use strict;` it would be window, and that would be pretty useless here..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this explains how to deal with this.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with `use strict;`.

Javascript does not pass around the `this` context, IOW: `this` is not bound to function invocation, unless your accessing a function using dot notation, calling a function as default will have a `this` as undefined, or window if not `use strict`, in both cases not very useful.

Because of this Javascript has things like `bind / apply / call` etc..

In your case `call` is most likely what your after.

so.

```
this[action.name].call(this, parameters);
```